# How to read Word document from C# on close event?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to upload a Word document to a webserver when it's closed in Word.
My code looks like this:

```
((DocumentEvents_Event)doc).Close += DocumentClose;

private void DocumentClose()
{
    var url = Config.GetValue("ApiUrl");

    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var response = client.UploadData(url, File.ReadAllBytes(_applicationWord.ActiveDocument.FullName));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip("Word " + WordTools.WordVersionValueToKey(_applicationWord.Version), e.Message, BalloonIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

But unfortunatelly this is not working. ReadAllBytes throws exception "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." Well, quite obvious this other process must be Word itself ;)

What would be a proper way to handle this? As far as I know there is no DocumentAfterClose event...

Comment: Would you try tu run your program with a breakpoint on the line throwing the exception and try this answer : http://serverfault.com/a/1980 (How to check which application has a file opened)

Comment: Maybe you can create a sepparated thread on the event, and in the thread create a loop with try/catch/delay, so it will run on background, try to open the file, if it's locked it will delay and retry again leaving time to word to release the file?

Comment: @Sidewinder94, it's quite obvious it's the word that's holding the file. We're in the middle of closing event ;)

Comment: @Gusman, that's sounds like a plan, but I'm not sure if that's "the proper way". Mabe you'll post it as an answer and we'll see how many people upvote?

Comment: The document will probably still be locked as long as you haven't released *all* COM objects related to it (not only the `doc` object, but any Range and other objects that depend from it). In addtion, I might try a loop that checks whether the document is still a member of the `Word.Application.Documents` collection. As long as it is, the document is still open in Word. But note that the file lock could still continue after that - you'd need to test.